# mysql fulltext search searching simple words like "part a"

Tags: mysql, search

I am building a database to store answers of some questions, with Answer, Tag, Tagmap, 3 tables. An answer record can have multiple tags which is used for searching. Tagmap is linking Answer and Tag. 
The application lets user to input a string to search, e.g. "2014 math part a". I used explode in php to split string into array, then make my sql statement, with keyword LIKE. Doing Like an a , probably all records will be returned.  What will be the proper way to search corresponding answer records. Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0):

You should ignore inputs which are too short, eg less than 3 chars. So `a`would be ignored but `aaa` you could search for. But you should also exclude some common words "with no meaning" like `the` in english or `der`, `die`, `das` in german.

So if a user enters `2014 math part a` I would only search for `2014`, `math` and `part`.

Also you should think about giving the user the possible to select some tags to reduce the amount of answers in which you search for your keywords before you do the "expansive" `like %keyword%`search.